# one sql request with results of previous

Tags: sql, iteration

My problem is it, I have a table composed by two columns. It describes folders. The first column is the `id` of the parent folder, and the second of the child folder. Then, with this table I can say which folder is in the folder `X`.

But I can have the folder 3 which is in the folder 2 which is in the folder 1.
What I am searching for is a way to find all parent folder from a folder's ID in one **SQL** request.

For example, from the `ID = 3`, my request must give me `[1,2]`.
So, with a while I can find all parent folders, but if the folder has 457 parents, it will be very heavy for just one folder !

The following request give the `id` of the parent :

```
$sql = "SELECT IDFolder1 FROM folder_has_folder WHERE IDFolder2='$this->id'";
```

But I don't know how many parents has a folder.

Have you a idea to make this ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please tag your question with DB you're using. You need hierarchical query and syntax is different for different RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
create table dbo.FOLDER (id_parent int, id_child int)
insert into dbo.FOLDER (id_parent, id_child) values (NULL,1), (1,2), (2,3)

with CTE as
(select id_parent, id_child
 from dbo.FOLDER
 where id_parent is null
 union all
 select f.id_parent, f.id_child
 from dbo.FOLDER f
 join CTE c on f.id_parent = c.id_child
)
select * from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived in Sql Server like this;

```
with CTE as
(select id_parent, id_child
 from dbo.FOLDER
 where id_child=3
 union all
 select f.id_parent, f.id_child
 from dbo.FOLDER f
 join CTE c on c.id_parent = f.id_child
)
select * from CTE
```

and in oracle like this:

```
select a.*, connect_by_root id_parent as root, connect_by_isleaf as last_level
from folder a
start with id_child=3
connect by id_child= prior id_parent;
```

Hope it helps.